# How does Wildfly know that a number of files need to be deleted if the "max-backup-index" attribute has been configured?

Tags: java, xml, oop, logging, wildfly

In order to implement [this issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/LOGMGR-57), i.e., `max-backup-index` feature for `periodic-rotating-file-handler` I am trying to understand how the `max-backup-index` attribute works in the `size-rotating-file-handler`.

**Attempts**

Wildfly reads the xml configuration:

```
<size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
    <rotate-size value="100K"/>
    <max-backup-index value="10"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</size-rotating-file-handler>
```

If the number of log files is greater than 10, then Wildfly will remove the files until 10 are left.

The Wildfly code that resides on Github has been viewed in order to understand what code is responsible for reading the `<max-backup-index value="10"/>` snippet and removing the superfluous log files.

[PeriodicSizeRotatingHandlerResourceDefinition](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/2b3f2bdd9533b28a30e32150f6c903cd50de3101/logging/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/logging/PeriodicSizeRotatingHandlerResourceDefinition.java)

```
class PeriodicSizeRotatingHandlerResourceDefinition extends AbstractFileHandlerDefinition {

    public static final String PERIODIC_SIZE_ROTATING_FILE_HANDLER = "periodic-size-rotating-file-handler";
    static final PathElement PERIODIC_SIZE_ROTATING_HANDLER_PATH = PathElement.pathElement(PERIODIC_SIZE_ROTATING_FILE_HANDLER);    

    static final AttributeDefinition[] ATTRIBUTES = Logging.join(DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTES, AUTOFLUSH, APPEND, MAX_BACKUP_INDEX, ROTATE_SIZE, ROTATE_ON_BOOT, SUFFIX, NAMED_FORMATTER, FILE);

    public PeriodicSizeRotatingHandlerResourceDefinition(final ResolvePathHandler resolvePathHandler) {
        super(PERIODIC_SIZE_ROTATING_HANDLER_PATH, false, PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler.class, resolvePathHandler, ATTRIBUTES);
    }
```

super refers to the constructor of the superclass, i.e, [AbstractFileHandlerDefinition](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/2b3f2bdd9533b28a30e32150f6c903cd50de3101/logging/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/logging/AbstractFileHandlerDefinition.java)

```
abstract class AbstractFileHandlerDefinition extends AbstractHandlerDefinition {
    protected AbstractFileHandlerDefinition(final PathElement path, final boolean registerLegacyOps,
                                            final Class<? extends Handler> type,
                                            final ResolvePathHandler resolvePathHandler,
                                            final AttributeDefinition... attributes) {
        super(path, registerLegacyOps, type, new DefaultPropertySorter(FileNameLastComparator.INSTANCE), attributes);
        this.registerLegacyOps = registerLegacyOps;
        this.resolvePathHandler = resolvePathHandler;
    }
```

super refers to [AbstractHandlerDefinition](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/2b3f2bdd9533b28a30e32150f6c903cd50de3101/logging/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/logging/AbstractHandlerDefinition.java)

```
abstract class AbstractHandlerDefinition extends TransformerResourceDefinition {

    protected AbstractHandlerDefinition(final PathElement path,
                                        final boolean registerLegacyOps,
                                        final Class<? extends Handler> type,
                                        final PropertySorter propertySorter,
                                        final AttributeDefinition[] attributes) {
        this(path, registerLegacyOps, type, propertySorter, attributes, null, attributes);
    }
```

**Current outcome**

At the moment it feels like I am lost in a labyrinth. I cannot find the code that explains the interaction between the `max-backup-index` attribute and the `size-rotating-file-handler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the [JBoss Log Manager](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager) not WildFly. WildFly just delegates everything to the log manager. Specifically what you're looking for is [this](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/handlers/SizeRotatingFileHandler.java#L258-L261).

That said this is a tricky issue. There's not a good reliable way to determine what files should be deleted. With a date suffix you can only do a best guess which isn't great. You don't want a log rotation to delete files you're intentionally trying to save.

For example say you have a `server.log.2015-01-01` and a `server.log.2015-01-01.save`. How would you know to only delete the first one? We don't want to delete the second as it potentially got renamed by a user.

There's also performance to consider. You don't want to block while a complex file matching algorithm is run. By default logging is blocking so any code trying to log will be blocked until the rotation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You could configure the "periodic-size-rotating-file-handler" to:

1. timestamp filenames (suffix)
2. rotate after a certain size is reached (rotate-size)
3. delete the last file after a certain number of file is reached (max-backup-index)

For example:

```
<periodic-size-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
    <formatter>
        <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <max-backup-index value="10"/>
    <rotate-size value="5m"/>
    <append value="false"/>
</periodic-size-rotating-file-handler>
```